# concat with to_char

Tags: sql, oracle

Write a SQL query to list `FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, STATE` and `ZIP` of Customers. `STATE` and `ZIP` should be displayed as STATE_ZIP (Ex: MO_65807)

```
select FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, concat(STATE,ZIP)state_zip
from customer;
```

It looks like that I have to combine state and zip within given specific form. (Ex: MO_65807). The query above shows that just combined with state, zip (Ex: MO65807). I think I need to use to_char in order to satisfy for the question. Is anybody know how to use those things at the same time?

Comment: `concat(STATE, '_', ZIP)`

Answer (score 0):

In MYSQL you can run the following query:

```
select FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, concat(STATE, '_', ZIP) as state_zip from customer;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CONCAT or another way of doing this would be

```
select FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, STATE||'_'||ZIP as state_zip from customer;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below script.

```
select FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, concat(concat(STATE,'_'),ZIP)state_zip
from customer;
```

OR

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME,STATE || '_' || ZIP AS state_zip
FROM customers;
```

Answer (score 0):

there are two methods.

1. you can use DOUBLE PIPE(||) operator

   - state || '_' || zip
2. you can use concat inbuild function

   - concat(state,'_',zip)

Please note that if the data type are different for both columns then you have to convert both in common data type.